# How can I send this to an onchange function for a select?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select element and I want to set the onchange function and send 'this', I've tried these:

```
s.onchange= function() {console.log(this.selectedIndex);};

s.addEventListener('click', myFunction.bind(s), false);
```

But no luck, I'm still getting 'undefined'.
What is this still showing undefined even if I am binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure why you'd want to send `this` over `event`, but the following should be close to what you're looking for?

```
var select = document.getElementById('select')

select.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  readSelection(this)
})

function readSelection(input) {
  console.log(input)
}
```